# Allow people to create interface implementation

Tags: c#

In .Net 6 is it possible to create a program that calls an Interface then allows someone else to implement the interface in their own program without needing to compile your code and reference their project?

The program would be running as a service and calling the Interface in a try...catch, throwing errors if not implemented, and can be enabled in appsettings.

If I create an Interface like this;

```
public interface IEventHandler(){
    async Task<bool> ProcessEvent(CustomEvent customEvent)
}
```

I would expect someone to process the class, also provided, do what they want with the event and return false if something went wrong.

I'd rather not resort to scanning for dll files and check if them implement the class so if that's the only way I'll be abandoning the idea.

Comment: You're basically talking about a plug-in system. This is exactly how people often implement plug-ins. You define the `IPlugin` (or whatever) interface in a library and other people then implement that interface in their own library. You then use Reflection to load assemblies from a particular location and find types within them that implement that interface. You can then create an instance and cast it as the interface type, then access the interface members via that reference.

Comment: Why nor raise the message on a message bus, something like RabbitMQ. The consumer would then receive the message payload from the bus, and do it's processing.  They would be coupled on the message contract and not an interface.

Comment: You code can reference external assemblies. In production code these often need te be signed though, to prevent people from injecting stuff into your trusted code. I mean, just think about it: this is a huge security risk. If you're running your app as an admin, and u some external assembly that has been tampered with to have malicious code in it, it has admin access.

Comment: You want someone to implement your interface, but you don't want to scan dlls to find someone's interface implementation. How do you think this should be implemented?

Comment: You could add the assembly qualified names of the implementors of your interface to configuration so that you don't have to scan the assemblies, but can load them directly. You'd still still have to create the instance(s) dynamically and verify whether they implement your interface though.